# How to scroll a specific div up after the page is scrolled to a fixed level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a HTML like below;

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: fixed"><div class="divb">red</div></div>
<div style="position: fixed;" class="diva">blue</div>
<div class="content1" style="background-color: #3333FF">content</div>
<div class="content2" style="background-color: #FF3300">content</div>
<div class="content3" style="background-color: #006600">content</div>
<div class="content4" style="background-color: #660099">content</div>
```

There is a bar on top, and a square in it's middle. Both are absolutely positioned to stay at top. I have 4 divs below them, each cascaded one after another, 400px wide and high. when content divs scroll, the bar and square will remain on top. But I want square to scroll up with content div 1. So after content div 1 scrolls up completely from the page, square should go up with content div 1, and should not be visible any more. How can I do this?

Below are two images showing what I am trying to say;

**Current**

[image: Current]

**Required**

[image: Required]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/pVkma/2/) is the fiddle.

Comment: You said absolutely positioned but positioned fixed???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pVkma/4/

Answer (score 0):

write position:absolute not fixed in red

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: absolute "><div class="divb">red</div></div>
```

Comment: sir,i have checked,this is working fine.. you can check @blasteralfred Ψ

Comment: it is moving with content 1 at the beginning itself. I dont want that. It should move with the bottom of content 1. refer screenshots i have attached.

Answer (score 0):

You need just move block with class divb into div with class content1:

```
div style="width: 100%; position: fixed"></div>
<div style="position: fixed;" class="diva">blue</div>
<div class="content1" style="background-color: #3333FF"><div class="divb">red</div>content</div>
<div class="content2" style="background-color: #FF3300">content</div>
<div class="content3" style="background-color: #006600">content</div>
<div class="content4" style="background-color: #660099">content</div>
```

Comment: refer screenshots i have attached.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
//get the height of the #top (I assigned #top id for one of your top divs)
var topHeight = $('#top').height() + 30;
//get all the top divs, it's better to wrap all the top divs in some container
//but you don't do that.
var topDivs = $('#top, .diva, .divb');
//handle the onscroll event
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  var rect1 = $('.content1')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  if(rect1.bottom <= topHeight){
    topDivs.css('top', rect1.bottom < 0 ? -topHeight : rect1.bottom - topHeight);
  } else topDivs.css('top', 0);    
});
```

We just add some `transition` property for the top divs to animate the transition. Here is the demo.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/pVkma/6/)